# ImageView inside AppBarLayout causes huge performance issues

Tags: android, performance, android-imageview, android-appbarlayout

I wanted to make a toolbar with image above it which would collapse upon scrolling the view below it but on some devices it causes a huge performance issue. Scrolling is painfully slow and I don't get why. On Samsung Galaxy S2 it works perfect but on S7 it's super super slow.

app_bar_layout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_image"
            android:src="@drawable/sky"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/actionbar_size"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                android:id="@+id/autofix_toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                autofit:minTextSize="23sp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: In manifest file add android:hardwareAccelerated="true" for <application> or <activity> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What folder is your sky image stored in? and what size is it? I had a very similar issue and it turned out it was because the image was in the wrong drawable folder and being scaled differently to what I expected. See this post: https://littlelostandroid.wordpress.com/2016/04/23/mishaps-with-bitmaps-part-1/

Comment: Well that was really unexpected but your answer worked well. I had it stored in drawable folder and when I moved it to drawable-xhdpi everything works well. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it! It was a real headache for me for awhile too. Cheers.